# Assign same number of elements to the column data based on number of elements (each row) of the other column

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

I have two column data, where first column contains "Number of Elements" and the second column contains "Stages" data. I want to assign the same number of data elements of "Stages" data to the new column ("Required") column based on the "Number of Elements" (first column) data.

[image]

Sample data:

```matlab
% Random data
data = ceil(10*rand(15,1));
data(:,2) = round(3*rand(15,1));
data =

     2     0
    10     3
     1     2
     8     2
     9     0
     9     3
     1     2
     4     1
     3     2
     9     1
     5     0
    10     1
     2     0
     3     1
     2     1
```

I'd like to create a cell array containing an array of `No of Elements` times the value in `Stages`. How can I create this cell array?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap a `for` loop around [`repmat`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) to populate your cell array

```
m = 15;  % your number of rows

% Random data
data = ceil(10*rand(m,1));
data(:,2) = round(3*rand(m,1));

% Initialise output
out = cell(m,1);
for ii = 1:m
    % store the required number of elements
    out{ii} = repmat(data(ii,2),data(ii,2),1)
end
```